# biconditional matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

So my professor gave me this question:

Assuming that $A\in M_{m\times n}$ and $B\in M_{m\times n}$. We will say that $A,B$ are biconditional matrices if there exist invertible matrices $P\in M_{m\times m}$ and $Q\in M_{n\times n}$ such that $PAQ=B$.

First, he asked us to prove that being biconditional defines an equivalence relation. That was very easy.

After that he asked us to find how many equivalence classes in $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{F})$ are there.

Or basically how many matrices there is in $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{F})$ so they are not  biconditional matrices.

So how do I do it.

I have no idea. I believe that you could always find such matrices except from the zero matrix which for that it will be biconditional matrices only to itself.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints.** The following is the key observation (and you should fill in the details).

> We can always use elementary row operations and elementary row operations to transform $A$ to a matrix that is **simultaneously** in reduced row echelon form **and** reduced column echelon form, i.e. there exist invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $PAQ$ is a matrix of the following form:
>   $$
> \left[\begin{array}{cc}I_k&0_{k\times(n-k)}\\ 0_{(m-k)\times k}&0_{(m-k)\times(n-k)}\end{array}\right].\tag{1}
> $$
>   (When $k=0$, the RHS above is the zero matrix and $I_k$ is void.)

In other words, every equivalence class in $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{F})$ contains a representative member of the above form. Now the question is: how many different (i.e. inequivalent) representatives of the form $(1)$ are there?

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer. I did not understand how can you determine that $B$ could be of the form you mentioned above.And assuming it is true, I think the answer for the question "how many different (i.e. inequivalent) representatives of the form (1) are there?" is depend if $m<n$  or  $m=n$  or  $m>n$ , because after trying to find the number of the possibilities of matrix $3x2$ I saw that  $k=0$  or  $k=1$  and nothing more. But if the matrix is  $2x3$  then you got 3 possibilities. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Ok. So I understand the first part. I think the answer to the question is 0 classes.Because every matrix has a rank and each matrix is equivalent to a matrix of the form (1),am I wrong ?

Comment: So, am I wrong ?